# Compiler used by Visual Studio for C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I have tried searching on the internet but could not find out the compiler used by Visual Studio for C++ applications.
I wanted to know whether it is freely available & whether it can be used for commercial applications.
Traditionally I have been using Turbo C++.

The problem with Visual Studio C++ Express is that it does not work with some applications.
For example, BRL-CAD which is an open source project works properly with the commercial version but gives some problems for the Express edition.
It seems that there is some problem with MinGW compiler as well.
I am told this by the people running that project.

Comment: What kinds of problems? Is it compiling but crashing? Are you unable to load the project into express?

Comment: I was chatting with the managers of that project & they said that I cannot use the express edition due to some problems. I dont know the details. Hence they recommended using Ubuntu.

Comment: You'll find you will get the best answers here when you know the details of your question. Try working with express and see what happens. Try to figure out what is wrong on your own and if you can't then you ask a question describing the exact problems you're encountering.

Comment: My question was not regarding why BRL-CAD is not working with Express!
I had only given that as a example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio uses the same compiler for all editions.  So, the Express edition uses the same compiler as the Professional edition.  There are also no restrictions on producing commercial applications, in either case.  There are differences in the advanced features offered by the IDE, but the compilers are the same.  So whatever your problems are in getting the project to work, it is nothing to do with the compiler.

Comment: but rest aside that problem, can you tell me how to get a sepparate copy of only the compiler?
because I want to try building my application created in Qt using Qt Creator IDE, so that I can compare it with MinGW compiled application.

Comment: Note: in the Express edition, some versions of the compiler are missing (e.g. 64-bit compiler), and the linker does not come with the Profile Guided Optimization feature (and since PGO results in the compiler being called, it is arguably a missing compiler feature). I believe everything else is the same. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hs24szh9(v=vs.120).aspx